# What does "Revision translation affected" indicate?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In views there is a boolean field named **Revision translation affected**. The description for the field is "*Indicates if the last edit of a translation belongs to current revision*". To me it is not so clear. What exactly does it mean?

Does it indicate what language that was changed in that revision? And what happens when non-translatable fields are edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this explanation in code comments:

> If a translation has changes in a certain revision, the translation is
>   considered "affected" by that revision, and will be flagged as such
>   via the "revision_translation_affected" field.

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/entity.api.php#n102

Comment: That link doesn't really work anymore, here is a better one to the change records which also describes the functionality. https://www.drupal.org/node/2897586